# responsive handling with display: none

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, responsive, display

I'm trying to understand if using the css property `display: none` with media queries is a safe approach to display different layouts between mobile and desktop.  I'm using `react` and `material-ui` for my frontend and as my layouts have become more complex, I've found that setting the `display` property to `none` is an "easy" approach to display specific layouts for various screen sizes.

With regards to SSR, I think this is a safer approach than using the [useMediaQuery](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/) hook.  I understand that I may give up performance because no matter what the size screen is, both mobile and desktop components are called on render.

Should I be considering anything else besides performance (and using a class based component) as a potential pitfall to this approach?

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import Mobile from './components/Mobile';
import Desktop from './components/Desktop';


const styles = theme => ({
  hideOnMobile: {
    // max-width media query between 0 and md
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      display: 'none'
    }
  },
  hideOnDesktop: {
    // min-width media query from md and up
   [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      display: 'none'
    }
  }
});


class ResponsiveComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className={classes.hideOnMobile}>
          <Desktop />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.hideOnDesktop}>
          <Mobile />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(ResponsiveComponent);
```

Comment: I'm curious of this as well, since sometimes for me adding "display: none" does not work for me. Maybe due to nesting of divs and html elements, not sure.